# Como obtener en una variable C# el texto de un Documento (pdf o word) almacenado en base de datos SqlServer

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server

Saludo.

Dentro de un proyecto que estoy realizando necesito subir documentos (PDF, DOC o DOCX) a una base de datos para luego realizar las siguientes tareas:
1) realizar busquedas en el contenido de los archivos y listar los registros que coincidan con los criterios de busqueda.
2) Extraer en una variable el texto completo de un archivo deseado ya almacenado en la base de datos

¿como puedo hacer ésto con base de datos SQL Server y C#?
¿es posible hacer esto usando mysql?

muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez pueda ayudar revisando los siguientes enlaces :

http://ltuttini.blogspot.com/2010/03/aspnet-guardar-imagen-base-de-datos.html

http://ltuttini.blogspot.com/2011/03/aspnet-grabar-archivo-en-base-de-datos.html